# VBA: Is there a way to apply a single formula to a column without looping through each cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite new in VBA and was looking for ways on how to apply the same formula to all cells in a column. I have 5000 rows and I would simply like to multiply row values in Column 1 with row values in Column 2 and show the results of the same row in Column 3.

I have tried looping through each of the cells:

For i = 1 to 5000

Next i

but the calculation was slow and was wondering if there is another way to calculate all 5000 rows quicker.

I actually have 60 columns with different formulas and conditional statements which slows down the calculation process. I am actually looking for a simpler way to 'BULK' apply a certain formula to the whole column.

Comment: Yes, there is, e.g. `Range("C1:C5000").Formula = ("=A1*B1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code makes `Column1*Column2=Column3` using *Formula* property of *Range* object without a looping

```
Sheet1.Range("C1:C5000").Formula = "=RC[-2]*RC[-1]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jim! Instead of pasting a formula into the cells, is it possible for VBA to undertake the calculation and paste the results instead or would it have to go through the looping if this is the case?

Comment: Sure, it possible. try like this; Sheet1.Range("C1:C5000") = Application.Evaluate("(A1:A5000)*(B1:B5000)")

Comment: I have a follow-up question... was wondering why this do not add properly:

Comment: .Range(M6:M5004) = Application.Evaluate("(B6:B5004-B5:B5003)*(L5:L5003)+(M5:M5003)"). In an excel row, the formula looks like: M6=(B6-B5)*L5 + M5. I would like to apply the same formula from Row 6 to Row 5004. At Row 6, this formula calculates the correct number; however, the succeeding rows ignore the value in the M column. I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: I guess there probably would be circular reference problems on the M column because of (M5:M5003).

Comment: Instead Sheet2.Range("M6:M5004").FormulaArray = "=((B6:B5004)-(B5:B5003))*(L5:L5003)+(M5:M5003)"  works well.

Comment: You can add some codes to copy only the resulting values onto M column's range to prevent from the calculation; 
    Sheet2.Range("M6:M5004").Copy
    Sheet2.Range("M6:M5004").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Comment: Many thanks Jim! I ended up as suggested with slight revisions: Sheet1.Range(Cells(6, 13), Cells(MaxRow, 13)).Formula = "=(B6-B5)*L5+M5" then Sheet1.Range(Cells(6, 13), Cells(MaxRow, 13)) = Sheet1.Range(Cells(6, 13), Cells(MaxRow, 13)).Value

Comment: This seems to work well but I just don't know what's happening behind what I don't see.

Comment: I just have an observation... This macro is called/activated from another worksheet and I get a "run-time error 1004 : Application-defined or object-defined error" with "= Application.Evaluate" (i.e. the worksheet wherein the data is calculated and saved in not the active sheet). However, if I run the macro with this worksheet active, I don't get any error. Not sure if I am supposed to have this sheet active ALWAYS when running "=Application.Evaluate"

Comment: To avoid the run-time error, you should specify the parent object of  the address(such as B6:B5004...) in Application.Evaluate.

Comment: Aha. That's it. I've been scratching my head. Many thanks again Jim - that was very helpful!